# Escape double quote inside double quoted string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, replace

I am having an issue, and I could not find the pattern in JavaScript to do it.

I have a string like this:

```
var project = '(Project=" my project "blah" ")';
```

I want to get this result

```
(Project=" my project "\blah\" ")
```

I want to escape the double quotes inside the double quotes with backslash.

Answer (score 0):

You should put a backslash before the character you want to escape.

```
var project = '(SANCOA4Project=" my project \"blah\" ")';
```

Comment: I think OP wants to do it programmatically. My guess is the variable is not really a hardcoded string.

Answer (score 0):

If the escapes are needed later, by another tool that evaluates `" my project "blah" "`, then you'll need to provide two backslashes for each quote:

```
var project = '(SANCOA4Project=" my project \\"blah\\" ")';
```

The first `\` in each pair will be consumed by JavaScript with the `'...'` string, leaving `\"` for the other tool to evaluate.

Comment: but how i do it with regex?

Comment: i need to search the double quotes inside the double quotes and place the backslash but how?

Comment: @RodolfoSoares If you can, fix it at the source of the value. The point of escaping is to remove ambiguity, distinguishing syntax delimiters and characters. Trying to figure them out after-the-fact, at runtime, is likely going to be error-prone.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to escape the escape characters to escape the double quotes inside double quotes in a later usage:

```js
var project = '(SANCOA4Project=" my project \\"blah\\" ")';

console.log(project);
```

Comment: but how i do it with regex?

Comment: i need to search the double quotes inside the double quotes and place the backslash but how?